# Как объединить в таблице строки в одну в столбце?

Tags: html

Как объединить в таблице строки в одну в последнем столбце?

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю, что будет полезно - [Rowspans & Colspans in CSS Tables](https://www.sitepoint.com/rowspans-colspans-in-css-tables/)

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю, в чем проблема использовать средства html, а именно [тэги таблиц](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/tablitsy), и уже там [объединить ячейки](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/tablitsy/obedinenie-yacheek) одним атрибутом. Для этого нужно divы поменять на tr\td\tbody и тд... 5 секунд делов, +классы можно оставить

Comment: Блочная верстка имеет ряд преимуществ.

Comment: @Dmitriy если использовать теги таблиц, блочная верстка куда-то пропадет?